# Serve raw files as text/plain on Django server

Tags: python, django

I have a Django App that's used to upload KML files along with a `state` value in a model `KmlModel`. To display these KMLs, I want to access them as raw files on the server which I'm trying to do as follows:

```
def result(request): #mapped to /getFiles url
    state = request.GET['state']
    res = KmlModel.objects.get(state__state__exact=state)
    obj = res.Kml_File.url
    serve_file(obj)

def serve_file(filename):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="text/plain")
    for line in open(filename):
        response.write(line)
    return response
```

The problem I'm facing is, that on trying to access `/getFiles?state=SomeState`, it gives this error
`OSError at /getFiles
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/dynamic/RR.kml'` where `RR.kml` is the matching KML file for `SomeState`.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

**EDIT**

```
def result(request):
    state = request.GET['state']
    res = KmlModel.objects.get(state__state__exact=state)
    return HttpResponse(res.Kml_File.open(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

Models.py

```
class KmlModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Kml_File = models.FileField(upload_to='dynamic/')
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.state.state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're storing the full static URL for these KML files, but then in your `serve_file` method you're trying to open that URL as if it was a local file path, and read and serve the content.

Rather than trying to fix this, why not just redirect to the static URL?

```
res = KmlModel.objects.get(state__state__exact=state)
return HttpResponseRedirect(res.KML_File.url)
```

**Edit** Actually, I realise that your `KML_File` field is presumably a models.FileField. in which case, you can open it directly with `res.KML.File.open()`, so no need to pass the URL to your serve_file method.

Also, don't forget you need to return the result of calling serve_file.

Comment: This still downloads the file for some reason. I added `content-type='text/plain'` to response.

Comment: OK, now I see what you are trying to do. The thing is that the dev server will use the `mimetypes` module from the Python standard library to guess the type of your file, and there is no easy way to override that. However, when you move to production, you will be able to configure your webserver explicitly to treat ".kml" as text/plain.

Comment: And now I see there is an easier method, see my edit.

Comment: So you mean, use `obj=res.KML_File.url` and then `obj.open()`? or do you mean `return HttpResponse(res.KML_File.open())`?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to just do `return HttpResponse(res.KML_File.open(), mimetype='text/plain')`.

Comment: Doing that returns a `None` response. :(

Comment: Can you show your full code now (as an edit to the question)?

Answer (score 0):

Is `open()` the standard Python `open()`? If so this operates on files, not URLs (although I was unable to get the same exception when opening a URL with `open()`). Try instead:

```
import urllib2

def serve_file(url):
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype="text/plain")
    for line in urllib2.urlopen(url):
        response.write(line)
    return response
```

You could also try redirecting to that URL, however, I am not sure that the correct MIME type will be set for the `Content-type` response header.